# Dynamically add class objects to ArrayList in java

Tags: java

I know how to add objects to an `ArrayList`.

```
class LightBulb {
    int position;
    LightBulb(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}

public class MainBulb
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        LightBulb ob1 = new LightBulb(1);
        LightBulb ob2 = new LightBulb(2);
        LightBulb ob3 = new LightBulb(3);
        LightBulb ob4 = new LightBulb(4);
        LightBulb ob5 = new LightBulb(5);
        
        ArrayList<LightBulb> list = new ArrayList<LightBulb>(); 
        list.add(ob1);
        list.add(ob2);
        list.add(ob3);
        list.add(ob4);
        list.add(ob5);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add objects at runtime using a loop, like below?

```
int n = 100;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    LightBulb ob1 = new LightBulb(i);       // But here it is wrong as we are adding same object to the ArrayList
    list.add(ob1);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "adding same objects". In loop you are each time creating and adding new instance of a class, not the same instance.

Comment: As near as I can tell, that loop you have should run exactly as is.  What problem are you having with it?  What do you see happening, and what do you want to see instead?

Comment: Perhaps if you had tried running your code, you would see that it is working already, and saved everybody time.

Comment: @Andreas , I know the code  is working, but I dont think it is a right way to solve a the above problem. I understood the concept and I believe , adding same reference "ob1" to every object that was allocated , is not a good way of solving problem. Please point out the problem, if I was wrong.

Comment: *"I dont think it is a right way"* It **is** the right way. Or rather **a** right way. --- *"adding same reference `ob1`"* It's not the same reference, since each iteration of the loop creates a new, *different* reference to the new, *different* object. --- *"is not a good way of solving problem"* Why would using a local variable not be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

new operator in java always creates a new Java object. Your example is indeed creating new Light Bulbs. They are not the same object.

Comment: I understood the problem . But still , my doubt is : Was it logical to add same object reference to the objects creating in runtime as shown in the question .

Comment: @VyshakPuthusseri It's not the same object reference. The object reference changes with every loop iteration. If you are referring to the object name. Then, yes the object name should be something meaningful. I would have named it like bulb, maybe.

Comment: @VyshakPuthusseri You may want to read through if you still have queries - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/summaryclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

You are adding different objects each time. Just print and check once you will get clarity. From what I understood from your question, I will explain a possible misconception.

I think you are getting confused cause you are adding object with same variable name `ob1`. In Java, when you use the `new` keyword, it will create a new instance, so for each iteration you are getting new object.

Consider if you have lightbulb1 in your first iteration.

```
ob1=lightbulb1.
```

but in second iteration ob1 variable points to new object with value of 2, i.e

```
ob1=lightbulb2
```

This will be repeated till the end if the loop.

So, your list is filled with different objects at the end of your each iteration.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is actually giving output. I believe you are having confusion about assigning same object name "ob1" to each newly created object. This can be solved, if you directly add the dynamically created class object into the ArrayList without creating a reference to it.
Change the for loop as follows.

```
int n = 100;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    list.add(new LightBulb(i+1);        
}
```

I used i+1 to initialize, because in your question, you are initializing with value 1 to 5 not with values 0 to 4

Comment: I do not see any problem with the OP's code. It's always creating new Light Bulb object in his example too.

Comment: @SKumar I know code is working, but is it correct way to have same object reference to many objects in a situation like in the question?

Comment: @VyshakPuthusseri this is not any "more correct" than you have originally posted. Also, to be clear, you are still creating a reference to the object, you're just not creating a variable named obj1.